# Manipulating large graphs using JGraph

Tags: jgrapht, jgraph

I have an acyclic graph that has about 100,000 nodes.

I want to be able to edit the graph and basically visualize it by zooming in and out of portions.

My Question: Is JgraphT a suitable candidate for this type of an application?

Answer (score 1):

JGraphT isn't a visualization library, it's about graph structure and algorithms. It uses JGraph 5 for visualization, not the latest version [JGraphX](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html)(aka 6). JGraph 5 performs more poorly than 6, and I doubt it can hit 100k nodes.

If it's just visualization you're after, try a simple test case with JGraphX. I doubt it'll work out of the box, but with a bit a tuning, it's certainly possible.